# How to executing static members with Grand-Central-Dispatch?

Tags: objective-c, grand-central-dispatch, exc-bad-access, static-methods, ios7.1

I created a base class (CLASS_A) with two static methods:

```
    +(Class)ClassByName:(Nsstring*)name;
```

It return class according to a set of fixed names (e.g. class1, class2, etc)for classes derived from CLASS_A;

This is the static method i want to call in all the derived class.

```
    +(NSDictionary*)func1:(NSInteger)index;
```

This is the base class:

```
   @interface CLASS_A:NSObject{
   }
   +(NSDictionary*)func1:(NSInteger)index;
   +(Class)ClassByName:(NSString*)name;
   @end

    @implementation CLASS_A{
    }
    +(NSDictionary*)func1:(NSInteger)index{return @{@"0":@"testing base class"};}
    @end
```

These are the derived class:

```
    @implementation class1:CLASS_A{
    }
    +(NSDictionary*)func1:(NSInteger)index{return @{@"0":@"testing class1"};}
    @end

    @implementation class2:CLASS_A{
    }
    +(NSDictionary*)func1(NSInteger)index{return @{@"0":@"testing class2"};}
    @end
```

I execute func1 using the following syntax:

```
    [[(CLASS_A*)[CLASS_A ClassByName:@"class1"]class] func1:0];
```

The func1 works fine but if I execute the line in a queued block:

```
     dispatch_queue_t myQueue1 = dispatch_queue_create("myQueue1", 0);
     dispatch_async(myQueue1, ^{
    NSDictionary*ret= [[(CLASS_A*)[CLASS_A ClassByName:@"class1"]class] func1:0];
    });
```

...sometimes, I have an exc_bad_access, as the object that I called became null just after the call...

Is there anyway to prevent this?

Comment: “sometimes, when the func1 takes longer to process the information” I don't see any information processing in `func1`.  Your real `func1` probably does something that causes the problem.  Post your real code if you want better help.

Comment: I should add that the runtime never deallocates `Class` objects.  If you print the retain count of a `Class` object (by calling `CFGetRetainCount` on it), you'll see that it's -1, which is a special retain count that tells the runtime not to retain or release the object.

Comment: Basically the "real" func1 returns a dictionary with few keys based on the index passed as argument. It is a very simple function.
The problem could be related to the fact the func1 correct declaration has an integer?: 

       +func1:(NSInteger)index;

I will try to use a NSNumber instead...maybe for some reasons a pointer is needed to correct handle the queue...